# Why element creation requires the document object in DOM?

Tags: java, xml, dom

As noted by [others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1391687/java-create-dom-element-from-element-not-document/1402006#1402006), in Java, with the default W3C DOM libraries, one is required to use the Document object a factory to elements, i.e.:

```
 import org.w3c.dom.Document;
 import org.w3c.dom.Element;

 Document d;
 Element e;

 e = d.createElement("tag");
```

Why is that necessary? Why conceptually a method can't create an XML element without knowing all of the target document? Why I can't just instantiate using 'new' or something to that effect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the DOM API is heavily interface-based. `Document` and `Element` are both interfaces, implemented by the various implementations of the API. As a result, you can't just instantiate the Element, since you don't know which implementation to use. All node creation must be therefore be done using factory methods. That was a design choice made by the DOM API designers.

If you want a DOM API that's easier to live with, try [XOM](http://www.xom.nu/), [JDOM](http://www.jdom.org/) or [DOM4J](http://dom4j.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: I would've answered "because the DOM API is badly designed..." but I guess yours is more thorough :) It's one of those API:s where they've crammed in every single design pattern without apparently really understanding them.

Comment: It's pretty awful, yes, but thankfully we can usually use one of the alternatives.

Comment: The question that follows then is why CreateElement() isn't static?

Comment: Because interface methods cannot be static. ;)

Comment: @maayank: If it were static, it would have to go on the class that implements `Document` - and you don't know what that class is.

Comment: Doesn't `dom4j` have the same problem?